# C# HttpClient Multiple Authorization levels

Tags: c#, authorization, dotnet-httpclient

Im using bearer token auth to access an api like this

```
message.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);
```

But on the server with the api, they now have added basic authentication aswell, meaning i first have to authenticate on the server with basic auth and then authenticate against the api with token.

How can i achieve that with HttpClient?

Comment: Sounds like they have configured the auth incorrectly. It should be basic or bearer not both.

Comment: Yeah i agree. But this is a temp setup before the api is public. But i have to access it still to test.

Comment: Well I think this is one of the rare cases where you can't

Comment: I got to the same conclusion after 2 hours of SO before this thread. But now i know for sure. Thanks :)

Comment: Just speculating, but maybe they're expecting you to hit a specific endpoint with basic auth to acquire a token, then use that token with the rest of the API as you've shown above? You say "they" added basic auth. Maybe you should ask "them" how exactly that works. If they show you a raw request/response or cURL example or something we could help you translate that to HttpClient.